# Maximum area for fixed perimeter of a triangle

Tags: calculus, geometry, problem-solving

I'm trying to prove that the triangle of largest area for a given perimeter is equilateral, but I'm having some difficulties.

I've done 2 different proofs for a similar problem but for rectangles - one proof uses the AM-GM mean inequality and the other uses algebra and a little calculus.

I can't manage to use a similar method for the triangle problem - with the algebra/calculus method, we only have 2 equations (one for perimeter, one for area) but 3 unknowns (each side length of triangle) so it looked like I was going to have to do it with respect to 2 different variables at the same time.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to approach this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron's_formula)?

Comment: Ahh that's a thought, thanks !

Comment: Straight AM-GM.

Comment: @Taimur: You are welcome! I hope you have solved the problem by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Using Heron's formula, $\triangle^2=s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c) $

Using $AM\ge GM$, $$\frac{s-a+s-b+s-c}3\ge \{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)\}^\frac13$$

or $(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)\le (\frac s3)^3$ the equality occurs when $s-a=s-b=s-c$ ie when $a=b=c$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how come the area is abc/4R and what is R?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleArea.html

Comment: You cannot just fix $R$