# When does a polygon gives the maximum area?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, polygons

I have a polygon with $n$-vertices and of fixed length, I need to find a condition for which the polygon gives the maximum area without using isoperimetric inequality.

1. I tried with the simple polygon "Triangle" ($n=3$) and find that it gives maximum area when it's 3 sides are equal. ([See here for proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253851/maximum-area-for-fixed-perimeter-of-a-triangle))
2. Next, I break one side of the triangle to form a Quadrilateral ($n=4$). And find that it gives maximum area when it is a Square. ([See proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128825/maximum-area-of-rectangle-with-fixed-perimeter))

My intuition tells me that if I increase $n$ then the corresponding polygon will give maximum if their sides are all equal, I assumed this is true for $n=k$ but I am unable to show this for $n=k+1$. Or is there is any other way to prove it? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: All sides and all angles are equal, not just all sides. But yes, that's the right answer. I don't know if induction is the way to prove it, though; a square and a regular pentagon don't have much in common.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868026/given-a-polygon-of-n-sides-why-does-the-regular-one-i-e-all-sides-equal-encl

Comment: Any generalization to 3D will be very messy, as there are not regular polygons with $n$ faces for every $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a plane $n$-gon with perimeter $L$ and maximum area.

If there are two sides whose lengths differ then there are two adjacent sides $AB$ and $BC$ with different lengths. If you replace the triangle $ABC$ with an isosceles triangle $AB'C$on base $AC$ with $|AB|+|BC| = |AB'|+|B'C|$ you will increase the area of the polygon, contradicting the area maximality.

I suspect a similar argument can prove the angles are all equal. I haven't thought that through.

**Edit.** In fact both my argument for the equality of the side lengths and the argument for angles is the core of the answer at this question, linked from the comments:
[Given a polygon of n-sides, why does the regular one (i.e. all sides equal) enclose the greatest area given a constant perimeter?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868026/given-a-polygon-of-n-sides-why-does-the-regular-one-i-e-all-sides-equal-encl)

To extend the question to three dimensions requires a definition of the area of a polygon that might not be planar. You will have to clarify the question.

Comment: What about the existence of such a polygon attaining the maximum (not supremum) area with given perimeter?

Comment: @AlexFrancisco That does indeed require some further argument, as in the linked question. This subtlety may or may not matter to the OP.

Comment: I want to mean "The area of the polygon in 3D space" by "the volume of a closed surface in that space". My question is can this approximation procedure be extended so that we can prove that a simple closed surface with fixed surface area gives maximum volume iff it is a spere?

Comment: @SujitBhattacharyya It is true that the sphere maximizes volume for given surface area, but I haven't studied a proof. For sure there are not enough regular ones like the regular $n$-gons to do the job. The wikipedia page may answer all your questions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality