# The perimeter of an Isosceles triangle is P inches. Find the Maximum area

Tags: calculus, derivatives

this question is on application of derivatives and I can't understand how the formula of the perimeter would be derived to the maximum.

Comment: Have you seen https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253851/maximum-area-for-fixed-perimeter-of-a-triangle?rq=1

Comment: Maximum area is obtained when all sides are closer to each other. Eg: 4,4,5. Etc

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be one of the equal sides. If the angle between a side and base is $t$, we have perimeter $2x+ 2x\cos t = P \implies x = \frac{P}{2(1+\cos t)}$. Now maximize the area $\frac12(x\sin t) (2x\cos t) = x^2 \sin t \cos t =P^2 \frac{\sin t \cos t}{4(1+\cos t)^2}$. Do your own calculus and check that you will $t=\pi/3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let the sides of the triangle be $$2x+y=P \implies 2x=P-y$$ ($y$ is the base)

Area would be:

$$\frac{y\cdot\sqrt{x^2-(\frac{y}{2})^2}}{2}$$

$$=\frac{y\sqrt{4x^2-y^2}}{4}$$

$$=\frac{y\sqrt{(P-y)^2-y^2}}{4}$$

$$=\frac{y\sqrt{P^2-2Py}}{4}$$

Now we can take derivative of this with respect to $y$ and find the maximum area. However, a trick we can do here is to square the expression $A$, find the maximum of $A^2$, and square root the result.

$$A^2=\frac{y^2(P^2-2Py)}{16}$$

$$(A^2)'=\frac{P^2y}{8}-\frac{3Py^2}{8}=0$$

$$\frac{Py}{8}(P-3y)=0$$

$$y=\frac{P}{3} \textrm{ or 0}$$

Obviously we don't one side to be $0$, so we get

$$x=y=\frac{P}{3}$$

And the triangle is an equilateral triangle!

---

Side note: Even if the "isoceles triangle" requirement is dropped, the optimal triangle (maximum area with fixed perimeter) is still an equilateral triangle.

Comment: It would be simpler with Heron's formula...

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, but I do not want to prove Heron's formula here, and it's not required. This is the elementary level that I suppose is around OP's level.

Comment: No need to prove it ; moreover, this kind of questions often come from people accustomed to olympiads where Herons's formula is wknown.

Comment: @JeanMarie This is nowhere near olympiad level, and calculus is generally not used in olympiad level. Heron's formula is a clear overkill here.